# ui:repeat - adding / removing elements from list does not work properly

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, facelets, mojarra, uirepeat

I have following code in my  .xhtml file

```
<h:form id="registration3Form">
<h:panelGroup id="terms_outer_panel">
   <h:commandLink styleClass="item-7" 
                    action="#{registerBusinessWizardController.addCourse}" 
                    value="#{msgBundle['registerThirdPage.panel.addSchedule']}">
   </h:commandLink>
   <ui:repeat value="#{registerBusinessWizardController.courses}" var="course">      
                    <h:panelGroup id="terms_inner_panel">
                        <div class="term">

                            <h:inputText id="price" styleClass="item-2" value="#{course.price}" />

                            <h:inputText  id="dateFrom" styleClass="date" value="#{course.date}" >
                                <f:convertDateTime  pattern="yy-MM-dd" type="date" dateStyle="long"/>
                            </h:inputText>

                            <h:inputTextarea value="#{course.additionalInfo}"/>

                            <p class="more">
                                <h:commandLink 
                                    value="#{msgBundle['registerThirdPage.panel.deleteSchedule']}" 
                                    actionListener="#{registerBusinessWizardController.removeCourse}">
                                    <f:ajax render=":registration3Form:terms_outer_panel" execute="terms_inner_panel"/>
                                </h:commandLink>

                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </h:panelGroup>
        </ui:repeat>
    //some other stuff
</h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

And when page is rendered. And user clicks addSchedule link I expect that ui repeat will add new  div class="term"
with empty values bind to inputs, because:

```
public void addCourse(){
    Course course = new Course();
    courses.add(course);
}
```

I am adding new Course object with null price additionalInfo and date to the list used by ui:repeat.

Instead I get new

```
<div class="term">
```

part with values copied from previous entry.

When I remove element from list (In managedBean proper object from list is removed) I see data from object which was just removed :/

Did someone encounter this kind of problem? 
Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be another `<ui:repeat>` bug. Mojarra's `<ui:repeat>` has (had) too many problems. First step is to exclude the component from being suspect by replacing it by a fullworthy `UIData` component, such as `<h:dataTable>`. If it works, then it's most definitely a bug in `<ui:repeat>`, otherwise it's just a bug in your own code (based on the code given as far I don't see any, I however assume that your bean is `@ViewScoped`).

If it's indeed caused by `<ui:repeat>` itself, then the first step is usually to upgrade to latest Mojarra version. This is [currently](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/) 2.0.6 for Servlet 2.5 containers and 2.1.4 for Servlet 3.0 containers. If that doesn't solve the problem, then you should look at replacing Mojarra by [MyFaces](http://myfaces.apache.org) which has a different and better `<ui:repeat>` implementation. If that isn't an option for some reason, then you should consider looking at a 3rd party component library which has an `UIData` based component which doesn't render any markup, such as [Tomahawk's](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk) `<t:dataList>`.